# AWS EC2 instance - Apache/Ubuntu 12.04 and Neo4j 1.9.1

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, neo4j, ubuntu-12.04

I've been fiddling around with this for awhile and figured I'd see if anyone can help me out.  I have a EC2 instance running Apache/Ubuntu 12.04 and have successfully installed Neo4j 1.9.1.  I didn't use Puppet or any Cloud Formation template for that matter, I simply installed Java 7 along with the stable Neo4j debian package and it's running perfectly fine locally if anyone else is having problems with Puppet.  When I run `#curl http://localhost:7474` , I get the following:

```
root@ip-xx-xxx-xx-xxx:~# curl http://localhost:7474
{
  "management" : "http://localhost:7474/db/manage/",
  "data" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/"
}root@ip-xx-xxx-xx-xxx:~# :7474/db/data/
```

My problem is I cannot resolve a connection with my elastic IP or public DNS, they both work as I am able to SSH to the instance and the "It Works" Apache message shows, however when trying to access port 7474, I get a timeout error:

`http://elastic.ip.address:7474`

I do have port 7474 as well as port 80 open to the world within my security group and still am unable to resolve a connection, so I'm at a loss.  Any help at all would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely that the management interface only listens on localhost by default. There is usually a flag to enable it on all interfaces, but it's usually a bad (security) idea to do so.

Alternately, you can access the management interface via SSH Port Forwarding:

```
$ ssh -L 7474:localhost:7474  elastic.ip.address
```

Once connected, you can point your browser at "localhost:7474" to see the remote management interface. Everything is encrypted, etc.

Comment: This was the problem, I actually wound up opening remote access and installing this authentication plugin : https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/authentication-extension, works great.